# Random undefined references in my library

Tags: c++, arduino

I am having an extremely strange issue with some of my functions in a library I have made for a grapical LCD which communicates with my arduino over hardware serial. It's just a simple wrapper for the serial protocol that the screen uses.

Basically, I am getting an "Undefined Reference to... " error whenever I call certain functions out of this library. However, other functions work fine, and I can not discern any syntactical difference between the ones that are working and the ones that are not.

For example, I have a box function. When I call it and give it the four integers it is expecting it works fine. So does `fill_box`, and `circle`, and `erase_box`.

But functions like `backlight` or `offset` or even the one called `arg` (to reflect the way I felt at the time...) cause the code to trigger undefined references. I can't figure out why... What is my mistake?

Here's an example of code that works fine:

```
#include <gLCD.h>

gLCD obj = gLCD();

void setup(){
    obj.fill_box(0,0,60,60);
    obj.erase_box(5,5,15,15);
    obj.circle(50,50,25);
}

void loop(){delay(1000);}
```

But as soon as I add anything like `obj.line`, like this

```
#include <gLCD.h>

gLCD obj = gLCD();

void setup(){
    obj.fill_box(0,0,60,60);
    obj.erase_box(5,5,15,15);
    obj.circle(50,50,25);
    obj.line(0,0,40,40);
}

void loop(){
    delay(1000);
}
```

then I get an undefined references. Same with `obj.offset`, `obj.blacklight`, and `pixel`.

I just don't know why this is happening. And I'm starting to get really discouraged that I can't even write a simple library... Anyway, here's the library in question:

This is `gLCD.cpp`:

```
#include "gLCD.h"

HardwareSerial Uart = HardwareSerial();

gLCD::gLCD(){
    Uart.begin(115200);
}

void gLCD::box(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x0F);
    Uart.write(x1);
    Uart.write(y1);
    Uart.write(x2);
    Uart.write(y2);
    Uart.write(0x01);
}

void gLCD::fill_box(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x12);
    Uart.write(x1);
    Uart.write(y1);
    Uart.write(x2);
    Uart.write(y2);
    Uart.write(0xFF);
}

void gLCD::circle(int x1, int y1, int rad){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x03);
    Uart.write(x1);
    Uart.write(y1);
    Uart.write(rad);
    Uart.write(0x01);
}

void gLCD::erase_block(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x05);
    Uart.write(x1);
    Uart.write(y1);
    Uart.write(x2);
    Uart.write(y2);
}

void arg(){
    Uart.print("this is bullsh*t!");
}

void offset(int x1, int y1){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x18);
    Uart.write(x1);

    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x19);
    Uart.write(y1);
}

void backlight(int duty_cycle){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x02);
    Uart.write(duty_cycle);
}

void line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x0C);
    Uart.write(x1);
    Uart.write(y1);
    Uart.write(x2);
    Uart.write(y2);
    Uart.write(0x01);
}

void pixel(int x ,int y ,int sr){
    Uart.write(0x7C);
    Uart.write(0x10);
    Uart.write(x);
    Uart.write(y);
    Uart.write(sr);
}
```

This is gLCD.h:

```
#ifndef gLCD_h
#define gLCD_h

#include <Arduino.h>

class gLCD{

    public:
        gLCD();
        void box(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
        void fill_box(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
        void circle(int x1, int y1, int rad);
        void offset(int x1, int y1);
        void backlight(int duty_cycle);
        void line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
        void pixel(int x ,int y ,int sr);
        void erase_block(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
        void arg();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Wow; I feel like a total idiot. Thanks though; now I can keep working on it. But damn... haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declared a function `arg()` in class `gLCD`, you are supposed to define it later as

```
void gLCD::arg() 
{
  // whatever
}
```

i.e. you have to refer to the previously declared function by using an explicit `gLCD::` prefix, just like you did it with `gLCD::box`, `gLCD::circle` and other "working" functions. Why did you define those older functions correctly (with `gLCD::`) and then suddenly started to omit that prefix?

The new functions that you currently have defined there (`arg`, `offset`, `backlight` etc) are seen by the compiler as simple freestanding global functions. They have nothing to do with your `gLCD` class. Meanwhile, functions `gLCD::arg`, `gLCD::offset`, `gLCD::backlight` remain undefined, which is why you are getting these errors.

If you wanted to define these new functions right *inside* the class definition (inline), then you'd be able to do it without an explicit `gLCD::` prefix. But since you are doing it *outside* of the class definition, in a different file, you have to use a qualified name, like `gLCD::arg`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `gLCD::` to some of your functions in `gLCD.cpp`. Leaving the class prefix off means that you declare a global function instead of the class member function.

Comment: I can't beleive I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your arg, offset, backlight, line, pixel functions are not written as part of your gLCD class

change

```
void arg()
```

to

```
void gLCD::arg()
```